# How to create search select box using block class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, adminform

I want to create a select box like the below

[image]

I know this can be done using Ui components, but i want it to be done using form.php class (block class)

Currently i am just using the simple select box

```
       $fieldset->addField(
            'customer',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Customer'),
                'title' => __('Customer'),
                'name' => 'customer',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->options->toOptionArray(),
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Please follow link [click here](https://webkul.com/blog/add-ui-select-with-search-filter-admin-form-magento2/)

Comment: But that is for ui component, which i already now. I want it in a block class, form.php

Comment: If you want to do live above screenshot then you need to use ui component. From block class this type of view is not possible.

Comment: @AveshNaik did you find any solution for Block? I am stuck in same situation. please let me know.